# Custom CorrelationId Spring cloud sleuth Finchley.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, mdc, distributed-tracing

I am currently stuck with one use case in spring-cloud-sleuth.
I am using Finchley.Release spring cloud in my pom and Spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASEץ

I implemented my own CustomTraceContext which extends CurrentTraceContext and have added a custom CorrelationId (X-P-TraceId) to MDC.

I am using log4j2.xml and I am able to see CorrelationId (X-P-TraceId) in log files.

Now I need to propagate CorrelationId (X-P-TraceId) to chain of microservices and 
also I am unable to  see CorrelationId (X-P-TraceId) in async threads (I printed MDC.getCopyOfContextMap() in async threads I see only X-B3-TraceId, X-B3-SpanId)?

Is that possible with Finchley.Release?

Is there any any sample configuration?

I referred [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#prefixed-fields) but unable to configure with this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please let us know, what you have tried so far and don't post such a blog of text. Format it please

Comment: Hi @Traxstar I added whatever I have done.
Will this edit suffice.

Comment: Hi @Marcin Grzejszczak Can you please help me

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest release train. There you can use the extra propagation keys feature (it will automatically propagate your custom header) and also define it as the one that should be added to mdc oob.